# How does ObjectDataSource relate to traditional MVC pattern?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

(Apologies for the vagueness of this question. It is the result of some muddy thinking on my part.)

I am designing a small website with an MSSQL DB.  I have just stumbled across the **ObjectDataSource** class. I think I understand it, but I don't see how it relates to the traditional MVC design pattern, if at all.

The class, according to Microsoft, is designed to sit between the UI (View) and the database, and as such, I would think of it as a Controller. It does indeed map UI actions to behaviours, but it also contains code for writing to the database, which is not something I would expect a Controller to do (but I may be wrong).

It seems to me that it is both the Controller and the Model, but I get the feeling I am not seeing something here.

That's a lot of words to say I am very confused. I would be very grateful to anyone who can point me at anything that might help me to understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the ObjectDataSource is to intermediate between the view and some code that retrieves your data, not to the database directly.  It is not a controller, but something that would call your code to get the data.  A better description would be from an MVP scenario, where in MVP the view can manage itself, and the ObjectDataSource is a control that makes that management easier.  However, the ObjectDataSource may make it harder to work with a traditional MVP or MVC design implementation out of the box, depending on the framework setup.

I personally don't like this control; I never use it as I'd rather code it so it's easier to see how the binding takes place, in addition to when the binding takes place.  My personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectDataSource is not used in asp.net MVC if that's what you mean "traditional MVC design pattern".  It's used primarily in WebForms development.

It's usually dropped onto a webform component and configured via the UI, although it doesn't have to be.  It provides an abstraction that allows other WebForms controls to interact with an object model in a manner that is similar to the way in which these controls work with Databases.  This object model may ultimately come from a database, but it allows you to insert your own database methodology in between.

WebForms does not lend itself to the traditional MVC pattern due to some technical issues which complicate using it in that way.  A cleaner pattern for use with WebForms is the MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern.